# strftime() method?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table in my database and the date column is in String format.
I tried using the strftime() function in a WHERE clause to get all the data for a specific month

```
 String whereStatement=Constant.daily.Col_Remove +" = ? AND  "
                        +Constant.daily.Col_carowners_id +" IN( " +idOfMergeData+" ) AND "
                        +"strftime('%m', '"+Constant.daily.Col_date+"' ) = ? ";
 String [] ArgValues={"0",date_in_month};
```

but no data is retrieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `Col_Remove` really contain strings? If not, don't use a parameter.

And you are using quotes around the date column name, which makes it into a string and not a colum reference. Remove them:

```
                   +"strftime('%m', "+Constant.daily.Col_date+" ) = ? ";
                                   ^                           ^
```